# How can to form a date variable starting of some other variables?

Tags: vba

I`m trying to set a date variable starting of some string variables... I`m using the split function to extract the strings of a major string that is compose of some dates, these string is like 15aug x 28sep..so I need extract the day and the month from the substring...follows a party of the code below..

```
        Sub testdates()

        Dim sec(0) As String
        Dim daycomplete As String
        Dim datestart As Date
        Dim Valuedate2 As Date
        Dim instrument As String
        Dim shConfirmation As Worksheet
        Dim wbGuiaconfirmation As Workbook
        Dim splitinstrumente() As String

        Set shDadosoff = Worbooks("ControlSeptember").Sheets("Dados")
        Set wbControl = Worbooks("ControlSeptember")
        instrument=shDadosoff.Range("B"& ActiveCell.Row).Value
        splitinstrument()=Split(instrument,"","/")
        first(0)=splitinstrument(0)
        sec(0)=splitinstrument(1)

         if Len(sec(0)) = 5 And Application.WorksheetFunction.IsNumber(Mid(sec(0), 4))

        Day = 1
        month = Mid(sec(0), 1, 3)
        year = Mid(sec(0), 4)
        daycomplete="day&"/"&month&"/"&year&"/""
        datestart =CDate(#daycomplete#)
        Valuedate2 = WorksheetFunction.WorkDay(datestart, 2, ferall())

 End sub
```

Someon Can help me?

Comment: As pointed out by @JonnyAggro, we need to see code that looks like it could possibly run. Add `Option Explicit` to the top of your module and compile the code, fixing as needed.

Comment: I see `if Len(sec(0)) = 5...`, but I don't see `End If`, so this can't compile.

Answer (score 1):

Unless I'm missing something you can just split by the "x" delimiter and parse the right three characters as the month,  and the remaining left characters as the day number.

Example:

```
Dim mydates as variant
dim mystring as string
Dim z as integer

Mystring = "15aug x 28sep"

Mydates = split (mystring, "x")

For z = lbound(mydates) to ubound(mydates)

    Debug.print "month: " & Right(Trim(mydates(z)), 3)
    Debug.print "day: " & left(Trim(mydates(z)), len(Trim(mydates(z))) - 3)

Next
```

Comment: the problem is that my string have different types, for example bmf roll, in this case I want remove the space..so I need two types of delimiter..

Comment: Please consider explaining how this does **not** resolve the original problem you described, which is how to get the dates out of "string is like 15aug x 28sep"

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure where to begin here...

shDadosoff and wbControl aren't defined anywhere.

They are then set to new instances of "Worbooks(...", not "Workbooks(..."

I assume you want to set daycomplete equal to a formatted date e.g., 9/14/2014, but that should be done like so:

```
daycomplete = day & "/" & month & "/" & year
```

or rather, I think:

```
daycomplete = Day & "/" & month & "/" & year
```

I'm not sure why you have # signs around "daycomplete"

and ferall() isn't defined anywhere either.

Comment: I spelled wrong workbooks only in the code above but in my code is written correct ,and ferall exist in the code, only I forgot of put in there..and the daycomplete like you put don't work, the VBA sad that expected end of statement!

Comment: @MoisesBarbosa it is clear from the code you have posted in your revised question that you did **NOT** correctly copy Jonny's code.  It should be `day & "/" & month & "/" & year` but you have `"day&"/"&month&"/"&year&"/""`.

Comment: Because you didn't use it *correctly*. Observe the differences between what you are attempting to do, and what Jonny suggests that you do. You will note that your statement is **very** different, and will cause the compile error you are indicating in the comment: "Expected end of statement".